# Xcode custom Seque Action

Tags: ios, xcode, button, action, segue

I want a button action to invoke a custom seque. My custom seque is called "ClockSeque". I've searched through the asked questions and I can't find an answer to this question. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

PS: I have already created the .h & .m files called "ClockSeque.h & ClockSeque.m" and they are of class type UIStoryboardSegue.

Comment: How do I make a button action invoke a custom seque?

Comment: Here is the code I have;

`- (IBAction)submitButton:(UIButton *)sender { 
NSString *pin = _pinTextField.text; 
if (pin == @"1234") { 
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ClockSeque" sender:self];
 } 
else _errorLabel.text = @"Incorrect PIN"; }`

Answer (score 0):

In IB, connect a segue from the current view controller to the destination view controller. Name the segue, set the type of the segue to custom, and give the name of you custom segue class. Finally, in the button action call `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` with the name of the segue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That piece of code goes in just fine without warnings or errors however the button doesn't do anything when clicked. Any thoughts?

`- (IBAction)submitButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    
    NSString *pin = _pinTextField.text;
        
    if (pin == @"1234") {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ClockSeque" sender:self];
        
    }
    else _errorLabel.text = @"Incorrect PIN";
}`

Comment: Is that the name of your segue or the name of your custom class.

Comment: The name of the seque and class are the same. I have the Seque Class labeled as "ClockSeque" and the custom class is labeled "ClockSeque.h & ClockSeque.m"

Comment: The name of the custom segue class is not the name of the segue. For example in common table view/details view segue. The name of the segue is usually something like "ShowDetails" while the type of the segue is push. "ClockSegue" is a replacement for push, not a replacement for "ShowDetails".

Comment: Where do I find the name of the custom seque class then? Yes I'm a noob :-(

Comment: My "ClockSeque.m" file was empty because I didn't know anything needed to go in there. Once I put the correct code in there, thank you google, it started working. Thanks for your help.